# How to store a dictionary of dictionaries in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary

I have a problem where, I can create a table with lets say "x" rows and "y" columns. And create "n" of these tables. (Each having different rows and columns.)
[image: Table Image]

We can create table using this [Excellent Table Creation](https://gist.github.com/jineeshjohn/2044414)

Now each cell in these tables will contain some data. So I want to store this data and then use it in my post request.

i.e. What I want is to be able to store

```
{Table 1 :
         { row1 :
                 {
                   col1:
                        Data1
                 }
         }
}, 
  {Table 1 :
             { row1 :
                     {
                       col2:
                            Data2
                     }
             }
    },
```

How can this be implemented in Javascript ? 
Please comment if the question is not clear.

Comment: Is data static, or you don't worry about how data is obtained? This way I'll suggest you JS way to come up with table filling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a nested array:

```
var table = [
    [           // Row 1
        Data,   //  cell 1
        Data,   //  cell 2
        Data    //  cell 3
    ],[         // Row 2
        Data,   //  cell 1
        Data,   //  cell 2
        Data    //  cell 3
    ],[         // Row 3
        Data,   //  cell 1
        Data,   //  cell 2
        Data    //  cell 3
    ] // Etc
]
```

To access it:

```
table[0][1]; // Row 1, cell 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I am getting it right, but you mean something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var matrix_array = []; // the table hashes are kept here

  //matrixA and matrixB are samples
  var matrixA = {
      'row1':{ 
        'col1': 'a', 'col2' : 'a'
      },
      'row2':{ 
        'col1': 'b', 'col2' : 'b'
      },
  };

  var matrixB = {
      'row1':{ 
        'col1': 'c', 'col2' : 'c'
      },
      'row2':{ 
        'col1': 'd', 'col2' : 'd'
      },
  };
  matrix_array.push(matrixA); //push them in order
  matrix_array.push(matrixB);
  console.debug(matrix_array); //see the object in the console

});
```

hope this helps.this answer allos dynamic modification and configuration from an external file.

to iterate through them, use the forEach(function(element){}); on the array and then print each matrix by col and row.

To access them.. a better example:

```
matrix_array.forEach(function(matrix){
    console.debug(matrix.row1.col1);  //print the element 1 1 from each matrix
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to store that data in array not in object :

var $tables = $("table:eq(1)");

var data = [];

```
$tables.each(function() {
    var $table = $(this);
    var dataIndex = data.push( [] ) -1; // Table index

    $table.find('tr').each(function(row,v) {
      $(this).find("td").each(function(cell,v) {
        if (typeof data[dataIndex][row] === 'undefined') data[dataIndex][row] = [];
        data[dataIndex][row][cell] = $(this).text();
      });
    });
    console.dir(data);    
});
```